# How to scroll completely to the top of large terminal text buffers w/o adding additional dependencies?

Tags: shell, terminal, sh

I have a couple shell scripts which output git diffs which can get very long. When this happens, the terminal is left scrolled to the bottom of that text.

Ideally I'd like to programmatically scroll to the *very top* of the text buffer in a way which is as platform independent as possible, without requiring additional software installation.

The following works to move cursor to top of the currently visible text, but not to the top of the entire text buffer:

`printf '\e[H'`

This does basically the same thing:

`printf '\e[0;d'`

But neither of these scroll completely to the top, they just move the cursor to the top of the visible text.

My platform dependent (macOS) workaround is here:

https://github.com/montehurd/gitshorts/blob/main/utility#L3

Any pointers for how to scroll to the very start of the text buffer?

Comment: Use a pager. The first page of output will stay on screen.

Comment: `git diff | less`

Comment: Less unfortunately screws with navigation between diffs - my scripts use the left and right arrow keys and less intercepts these keypresses and instead just moves the text offscreen.

Comment: @dan Can you point me to fairly platform independent pager which comes pre-installed on most systems and allows users to simply scroll through long text?

Comment: @MonteHurd the most common pager is probably `less`, which dual licensed (GPL/BSD). `more` is part of the [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package, so it should be available on any Linux system.

Comment: @MonteHurd You mentioned navigating between diffs. If you invoke less with multiple files (`less file1 file2 ...`), you can navigate between them in less, with `:n` and `:p` for next/previous.